# Specific Columns Operation in Excel using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have excel(`test.xlsx`) sheet having multiple columns,`col1,col2,col3,col4` and so on.. I want to perform some operation on `col2,col3` and then the output `output.xlsx` having all the columns again with the updated `col2,col3`..

What I was trying..

```
df = pd.read_xlsx('test.xlsx')
col = ['col2','col3']
df_with_some_operation = df[col].<some_op>
df_with_some_operation.to_excel(output.xlsx)
```

Need help on this code so that all the columns including  col2,col3 get included in final `output.xlsx`

For better visualisation ... Check below, I do not want to change the column names, only want to update the content.. I picked this example to made it simplify .. col2 and col3 - > multiplied by 2 . just a note, there are multiple columns in actual, but only on 2 I have to do some work..

```
input.xlsx
col1   col2 col3
 1      2    3

output.xls
col1  col2  col3
1     4    6
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `drop`?

Comment: @roganjosh I need to keep all the columns as it is, just have to update col2,col3 . The excel sheet needs to be used with all the columns. Any better way you can suggest ?

Comment: Ok, so drop the columns you don't want before `to_excel`

Comment: @roganjosh I did not understood cleary, how its going to help to fix it ?

Comment: @roganjosh, I think I had framed the question wrongly, just updated it again with last line, I need all the columns in the `output.xlsx` that also includes the updated `col1 and col2`

Comment: To provide a good solution, you need to indicate what's involved in `<and then the logic work>`. Vectorised operations may be possible instead of the more generic but inefficient `pd.DataFrame.apply`.

Comment: @jpp I have used .applymap and then inside it lambda function..

Comment: ^Please include that in your OP

Comment: @jpp Please check the code, updated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign the result of [`pd.DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to `df[cols]`. This will leave the rest of your dataframe unchanged.

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

cols = ['col2','col3']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda c: translate.translate_text(...))

df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

If you want 2 new columns, you can use `pd.DataFrame.join`:

```
df = df.join(df[cols].applymap(lambda c: translate.translate_text(...))\
                     .set_axis(['col2a', 'col3a'], 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 7, 9], 'C':[10, 11, 12]})

df['A'] = df ['A']*3
df['B'] = df ['B']*2

df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: from @steveJ :"I need to keep all the columns as it is, just have to update col2,col3", I am just trying provide an example for his requirement (updating columns A and B and keeping column C as it is)

Comment: But this writes all the columns to the file

Comment: Thats what he asked

Comment: The question has been edited to change "apart from" to "including". Apologies :/

Comment: @KiruparanBalachandran I think you correctly got What I was looking for.. but le me do a test ..

Answer (score 1):

just include the newly generated columns in the orignal dataframe.

```
df_with_some_operation = df[col].<and then the logic work>
newcolums=["coln1","coln2"]


df[newcolums]=df_with_some_operation
```

now this way your dataframe **df** if you save will have all the orignal columns as well as the modifications you made.

Note: you can directly assign the new columns instead of writing down separately, like above. This is for understanding only:

```
newcolums=["coln1","coln2"]

df[newcolumns]=df[col].<and then the logic work>
```

Comment: *Sorry for misunderstanding , I just updated the last line, I need all the columns including the updated `col1 and col2` in the `output.xlsx`

Comment: @steveJ made modifications